# Kendo UI Grid sum aggregate on a column with an optional property

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm using the [Aggregates feature of a Kendo UI Grid Widget](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates) to display the sum of a grouped column. The column in question is bound to an optional field / property so when the data set includes a data item where property is not present (i.e. undefined), the sum ends up being [**NaN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) as you would expect.

The [Kendo DataSource calculates these aggregates *"when the data source populates with data"*](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-aggregate) but [does not include a feature to allow custom aggregates](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-do-custom-aggregate-functions) that would allow me to implement a version of sum that substitutes 0 for undefined values.

I can see where the sum aggregate function is defined in [kendo.data.js](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.data.js) but I would prefer not to change that if possible.

I have an idea how to solve this by writing a function to query the `$("#myGridId").data("kendoGrid").dataSource` but I'd like to know if there is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the latest code in [kendo.data.js](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.data.js) to my project version (**2013.1.319**) I see that they have changed the implementation of the sum aggregate function to handle this case by only performing the addition if the value is a number. Problem solved if I can get the project updated to the latest version of Kendo UI.

The code snippet below is at line 1369 of version [2014.1.416](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/2014.1.416-core/src/kendo.data.js).

```
sum: function(accumulator, item, accessor) {
    var value = accessor.get(item);
    if (!isNumber(accumulator)) {
        accumulator = value;
    } else if (isNumber(value)) {
        accumulator += value;
    }

    return accumulator;
}
```